# How to control the time of day in React Suite's DateRangePicker?

Tags: reactjs, rsuite

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to default the time of day in `DateRangePicker` to `00:00:00` for start date and `23:59:59` for end date.

The time of day simply defaults to the current time on the computer, which, frankly, is rarely what the requirements for a date range are. So It's hard for me to imagine there is no way to do what I'm trying to do. Check out the screenshot:
[image]

Here I picked the date range of Apr 22 to May 4. But notice the time of day. In order to set those to `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` respectively, I have to click on those times and scroll around to pick specific time of day, which is super annoying to do every time.

[The documentation](https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-range-picker/) says nothing about the time. Also their [GitHub issues](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/issues) page does not address this. What am I missing here. It seems like such an obvious oversight to not allow you to set a default time of day.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default time on the calendar via `defaultCalendarValue`.

```
<DateRangePicker
  format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  defaultCalendarValue={[new Date('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), new Date('2022-03-01 23:59:59')]}
/>
```

This has also been updated in the example on the rsuite official website.
https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-range-picker/#date-time-or-time